# Socket.io application running on Elastic Beanstalk - how to handle healthchecks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a very simple node.js application which creates a socket.io server on port 8081 and replies to simple, proprietary requests.

It's running fine on Elastic Beanstalk with Application Load Balancer. However, Elastic Beanstalk thinks there is a problem with the app as the healthchecks fail.

What would be an easy way to make health checker happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a REST endpoint at `<your_server>:<port>/healthcheck` which returns 200 HTTP response code with response may be `{"status": "ok"}` and point the ALB health check there.